# How to add a month to a date field using Soql query

Tags: soql

I am new to this entire setup and trying to create a query to add one month to a date field and compare with today's date.
ex:today <= first sign up date + 1

**I particularly need to add one month to the date and not 30 days.

Please advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please note: I am not using Apex or calculated fields. Running this query in developers console .  Something i wrote :  SELECT Name, accountId FROM Asset WHERE  company_id__c = '123145967990432' AND First_Charge_Date__c + 1 >= TODAY

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) to do what you want.

E.g.

```
SELECT Name, accountId 
FROM Asset 
WHERE company_id__c = '123145967990432' AND First_Charge_Date__c >= NEXT_N_DAYS:1
```

Or use `NEXT_MONTH` / `LAST_MONTH` for one month.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I need to compare with Today's date as well.                              ex: today <= first sign up date + 1

Comment: Since you can't do a `+1` operation in SOQL you will either need to change the date literal. E.g. `YESTERDAY <= First_Signup_Date__c ` or calculate the literal date in Apex.